# Gitea and Nginx Configuration

Tags: nginx, vps, ubuntu-18.04, gitea

I am trying to configure my Ubuntu 18.04 VPS to run both as an nginx webserver and private gitea server. I have the configuration mostly working except for any 404 from my domain gets passed through to gitea and shows the gitea 404. I would prefer any users of the main domain not be directed to Gitea.

Objective:

- Any subdomain except for git.domain.com should not be proxied to Gitea and should use https (working)
- Any errors for subdomains except git.domain.com should not go to Gitea (not working)
- git.domain.com should provide https access to gitea (working)

Tried:

- Using location /git/ for Gitea to separate the two and allowing the location / to return 404 after trying url. This causes all kinds of problems with 404 errors in Gitea and or causes git.domain.com to not use nginx

domain sites-enabled configuration:

```
server {

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name git.example.com;
    location / {
            proxy_pass https://0.0.0.0:3000;
    }
server_name *.example.com;
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
    #location / {
    #        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #}

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate <path>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key <path>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your config does not look really clean. Have a look here https://linuxserversetup.com/tutorial/self-hosted-git-service#nginx-forwarding-with-https and scroll down to "Change Nginx configuration file to HTTPS".

To run Gitea in a subfolder `git.example.com/git`, the Nginx config should be like this:

```
server {
  listen      443 ssl http2;
  listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name git.example.com;

  root        /var/www/example.com/html;
  index       index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.htm;
  }

  location /git/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }

  # ...
}
```

And in the Gitea config accordingly

```
[server]
PROTOCOL         = http
DOMAIN           = git.example.com/gitea
HTTP_PORT        = 3000
ROOT_URL         = https://git.example.com/gitea
```